# How to build a Firestore query chain based on a dynamic response from a promise

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

Let's say I need to query Firestore against a collection of subjects that I receive in a promise:

```
const subjects: string[] = await getSubjects(); //response: ['Math', 'Science', 'History'];
```

Since I don't know how many subjects might be returned in the promise at any given time, how would I go about dynamically generating the chain below so I can properly query Firestore?

```
ref.where('subject[subjects[0].toLowerCase()]', '==' , true)
    .where('subject[subjects[1].toLowerCase()]', '==' , true)
    .where('subject[subjects[2].toLowerCase()]', '==' , true);
```

The more subjects that are returned, the more `.where()` methods it would need to generate.

Comment: You might also want to read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48036975/firestore-multiple-conditional-where-clauses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a Query follows a builder pattern: when you call `where` it returns a `Query` and on that `Query` you can call `where` again.

So if you have an array of subjects and want to create a query of those, you can do:

```
var query = firebase.firestore().collection("bla");
['Math', 'Science', 'History'].forEach((subject) => {
   query = query.where(`subject[${subject}.toLowerCase()]'`, '==' , true);
})
query.get()....
```

---

Note that Firestore nowadays supports an `array-contains-any` operator, which scale significantly better for these types of operations and can deal with up to 10 subjects at once.

To use this you documents will need to contain an **array** `subjects`, like:

```
subjects: ['Math', 'Biology']
```

And then you'd query it with:

```
var query = firebase.firestore().collection("bla")
  .where('subjects', 'array-contains-any', ['Math', 'Science', 'History']);
query.get()...
```